# Why is log4 (n4) = Θ(log6 (n6))?

Tags: performance, runtime, big-o

Why is  log4 (n^4) = Θ(log6 (n^6))? Let n for example be n=2, then n^4=16 and n^6=64. Therefore log4 (16)=2, but log6(64)!=2.

Answer (score 1):

This is true because: `log_b(n^p) = ln(n^p) / ln(b) = p ln(n) / ln(b)`.

Indeed:

```
log_4(n^4) = (4 / ln(4)) ln(n) = Θ(ln(n))
log_6(n^6) = (6 / ln(6)) ln(n) = Θ(ln(n))
log_4(n^4) = Θ(log_6(n^6))
```